# Nightwatch dropdowns handling by passing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, automation, nightwatch.js

Below is the approach I have used in order to select values from a dropdown using nightwatch.As you can see this is not a good approach. We can't select the specific value from dropdown unless we click on the exact element.

```
    this.useXpath();
    this.click('(//td[@class="styles_selectDropdownContainer__2Vrns"])[1]')
    this.useCss();
    this.click('#react-select-6-option-1')
```

In selenium java there is a very good option like below

```
    Select fruits = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));

    fruits.selectByVisibleText("Banana");
```

I want to know of there is a similar approach can be used in nightwatch as well?

[image: HTML]

Comment: if the HTML has select and option for drop downs then you can use the Java -selenium code whatever you have shared. But HTML does not have Select and options tag even then it is a trivial job to be done in Java

Comment: Can you share the HTML code for better understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not built up using `Select` and `Option` tag so inbuilt selenium functions wouldn't work. Work around would be to click first on the parent span and then in list store every div (which is option), iterate the loop and for each web element if text matches with your desired text you can click on it.

**Code :**

```
 this.useCss();
 this.click("span[aria-live='polite']")
```

Now store options in a list :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.elements'); // use 
//div[contains(@class,'option')] as element selector.
```

Now iterate the list :

```
// Iterate over them.
  [].forEach.call(elements, function (element) {

    // Manipulate each element.
    element.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when click on css.  element click intercepted: Element <span aria-live=\"polite\" class=\"css-1laao21-a11yText\">...</span> is not 
clickable at point (672, 102). Other element would receive the click: <div class=\"select_searchSelectDropdown__2ZMLQ styles_select__1rwYx css-2b097c-container\">